# Apache - 403 Forbidden - changed dir for default in sites-available

Tags: permissions, apache2

I'm sorry if this is a repeated question, but i have tried all the possible solutions from the other answers...

I just installed apache, php5, ..., the works

I can access http://localhost and get the apache index.html located at `/var/www`

I did the following:
in sites-available:
sudo cp default mydefault
opened it and got this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

So i changed `DocumentRoot /var/www` to my folder and  `<Directory /var/www>` to my folder.
Inside this Directory tag, i changed `Allow Override` to `All` and inserted `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php`

I saved, and ran

```
sudo chmod 755 /myDirectory  
sudo a2dissite default && sudo a2ensite mydefault 
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And still get 403 forbidden when accessing http://localhost

Any help wil be appreciated, thanks

Comment: I am unsure why but in my system the file is named 00-default in both /etc/apache2/sites-available and /etc/apache2/sites-enabled. The contents of both files should be the same in order to avoid that error. Additionally I suggest you to "sudo apache2ctl stop" and "sudo apache2ctl start" in order to the changes to take effect. Sometimes a reboot fixes this issue. Please let me know if this helps  you in order to add it as an answer.

Comment: appart from the "00-" there is no difference at all, they are the same because the one in sites-enabled is a symlink to the one in sites-available. I did apache2ctl stop and start, no change

Comment: Post the configuration file you are actually using, not the one you used as a template. check the permissions on the directory and what is in the logs ?

Comment: Use 'tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log' as you load the site to glean the problem.

Comment: the problem was that i had SELinux installed, i think. I reinstalled linux, didn't "encrypt my home folder" and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*OP posted*

the problem was that i had SELinux installed, i think. I reinstalled linux, didn't "encrypt my home folder" and now it works. – André Alçada Padez Mar 5 '12 at 13:52